# Android SharedPreference value is getting cleared on app close

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-storage

I am saving my `UserId` on `SharedPreference` for future use. But that data getting cleared if I close that app or kill the app.

code used to save:

```
 SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.putString("USERID", valu1);
    editor.apply();
```

code to retrieve :

```
 SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        userID = app_preferences.getString("USERID", "");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to get the value if you don't close the app?

Comment: share the whole class code

Comment: @ZankrutParmar yes it's available.

Comment: Fixed issue by declaring a custom SharedPreferences. Called clear() function before saving another data. That caused me to delete this as well. This may help anyone.        SharedPreferences app_preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userData",0);

Answer (score 2):

The apply() method is asynchronous and works on a background thread. It caches the data in RAM and waits until it has sufficient resources to write the data to permanent storage. Considering this, if you immediately close your app, you might lose data. Unlike apply(), commit runs on the UI thread and synchronously, do it has a guaranteed write but pauses the UI thread for a moment. The wait is insignificant though. Consider using commit() instead of apply() and see if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make one session manger for that, which is separated class.

```
public class SessionManager {
   
    SharedPreferences pref;

    Editor editor;

    Context _context;

    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    private static final String PREF_NAME = "Android_Session";

    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

    // User name, Email,Id (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";

    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";

    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    /**
     * Create login session when user login first time call this.
     */
    public void createLoginSession(String phone, String email, String id) {
        
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
        editor.putString(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        editor.putString(KEY_ID, id);
        editor.commit();
    }

    
    /**
     * Check user is login or not if not.
     * This will used in dynamic app where session expired from server sideit will redirect to login page.  
     */
    public void checkLogin() {
       
        if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {

            // user is not logged in then redirect to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
            
            // Add flags launch modes
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get stored session data
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        

        user.put(KEY_PHONE, pref.getString(KEY_PHONE, null));
        user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));
        user.put(KEY_ID, pref.getString(KEY_ID, null));

        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     */
    public void logoutUser() {

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
        // Add Flags (Launch Modes)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);


        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Check if user login or not
     **/
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```

Now to retrieve values like

```
   SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
   HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
   String id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
```

To identify login

```
SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
 if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {                             
//ToDo
} else {
}
```